# angularjs ng-options key-value pair 3 levels deep

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a problem, i can't make 3 levels deep in ng-options, i was able to make work the 2 levels deep

Here is my code

Controller

```
$scope.names = {
            'Technology': [
                'Personal Computer',
                'Mobile Phone',
                'Console Game'
            ],
            'Healthcare': [
                'Blood Donation',
                'Injection',
                'Medical Care'
            ],
            'Housing': [
                'Repairs',
                'Gardening',
                'Plumbing',
                'Laundry'
            ]    
        };
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for (x, y) in names">
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedNames" ng-options="x for x in selectedName">
</select>
```

This is working but only 2 levels deep, what i need is 3 levels deep.

So the $scope.names will be like this

Controller

```
$scope.names = {
            'Technology': [
                'Personal Computer': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Mobile Phone': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Console Game': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ]
            ],
            'Healthcare': [
                'Blood Donation': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Injection': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Medical Care': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ]
            ],
            'Housing': [
                'Repairs': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Gardening': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Plumbing': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Laundry': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ]
            ]    
        };
```

How will i arrange my ng-options? it's not showing anything using `ng-options="x for (x, y) in names"`

Comment: Is that a valid JSON? Shouldn't that be an array of objects (inside Technology array for eg)? Any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 
 
$scope.names = {
            'Technology': {
                'Personal Computer': [
                    'some data1', 
                    'some data2'
                    ],
                'Mobile Phone': [
                    'some data3', 
                    'some data4'
                    ],
                'Console Game': [
                    'some data5', 
                    'some data6'
                    ]
            },
            'Healthcare': {
                'Blood Donation': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Injection': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Medical Care': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ]
            },
            'Housing': {
                'Repairs': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Gardening': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Plumbing': [
                    'some data', 
                    'some data'
                    ],
                'Laundry': [
                    'some data' , 
                    'some data'
                    ]
            }    
        };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for (x, y) in names" ng-change="getKeys(selectedName)">
</select>  
{{selectedName}}
<select ng-model="selectedNames" ng-options="y as x for (x, y) in selectedName"  >
</select>
{{selectedNames}}
<select ng-model="selectedNames3" ng-options="x for x in selectedNames">
</select>
{{selectedNames3}}

</div>
```